# Mysql - Counting NULL always returns 0?

Tags: mysql

Im trying to get this result:

```
NULL    350
google  98
yahoo   5
bing    4
```

With this query:

```
SELECT engine, COUNT(engine) AS count
FROM visits
GROUP BY engine
ORDER BY count DESC
```

But it returns:

```
google  98
yahoo   5
bing    4
NULL    0
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)` or `COUNT(aNotNullableColumn)` will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `COUNT(1)` instead:

```
SELECT engine, COUNT(1) AS count
FROM visits
GROUP BY engine
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7014/1)

Comment: WOW,thats a quick correct answer! Thanks alot =) BTW, why did it work?

Comment: @Sultanen count(colname) counts every line that contains a non-null(!)-value in colname. count(1) can be thought of adding an additional column with value 1 in every line of the query-result.

Comment: Thanks for the explination, well worth knowing =)